# How can i convert a FilePath to a File in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

For example I have this file:

```
$thumbnail = 'http://www.example.com/pic.jpeg';
```

I try this:

```
$thumbnail = file_get_contents($thumbnail);
dd($thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

I got this error:

> "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string"

Comment: Did you really intend to use the same variable for the input and the output?

Comment: @MandyShaw because I do not neet it else. Is it wrong?

Comment: It might be, if the two usages are of different data types. But let's see what others come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing it on disk? This worked in my tester.

```
use Storage; 

$url = "http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png";

 $contents = file_get_contents($url); $name = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1); 
Storage::put($name, $contents);
```